# Create a div dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

How can I create a div dynamically within a function, like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="notice" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

It would be very nice if I could create it also with jquery library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("id", "mydiv");

div.className = "notice";
div.style.display = "none";

// test case, append the div to the body
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

or with jQuery

```
$("<div id='mydiv' class='notice' style='display: none;'></div>").appendTo("body");
```

Be careful since in the jQuery approach an element is created and its innerHTML property set to the given markup. It is therefore both quite flexible and limited.

Comment: the jquery function works but it inserts at the and of the body

Comment: that's because my testcase has the "appendTo" at the end. remove that and use it as you see it fit.

Comment: even if i remove document.body.appendChild(div);
it realy doesnt work,

Comment: jQuery does not use innerHTML to append to the `"body"`. It creates the DOM element from the HTML provided by using an *off*-DOM `innerHTML` trick plus a document fragment -- to actually add the resulting DOM node to the document, jQuery uses regular DOM methods, like `element.appendChild` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the element with jQuery will allow it to be referenced by variable name

```
var div=$(document.createElement('div'))
  .attr({id: 'myDiv'})
  .addClass('myNotice');
```

Now we can reference the `div` variable in the rest of our script.

```
//put it where you want
$('#someElement').append(div.hide());

//bind some events
div.mouseenter(function(){
  var offset=div.offset();
  //more code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using just plain DOM:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.setAttribute("id", "mydiv");
mydiv.setAttribute("class", "notice");
mydiv.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
whateverContainer.appendChild(mydiv);
```

Comment: `setAttribute ('class', '...')` is correct, but doesn't work in IE pre-v8 because IE doesn't know the difference between an attribute (`class`) and a property (`className`). You should always use DOM Level 1 HTML properties (`mydiv.id= 'hidden'; mydiv.className= 'notice'; mydiv.style.display= 'none'`) in preference to `setAttribute` partly due to these IE bugs and partly because the property way is much simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Huh. I thought the property shortcuts were browser-invented stuff that never got into any DOM specification. I see [I am wrong](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html). Thanks, bobince.